# Jquery ui datepicker: disable click on days leaving active change of month

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a Jquery UI Datepicker directly printed in my page (not popup, but directly in the DOM).

I would like to disable click on some (or all) days leaving active only buttons to change month and year displaied. So user can change month viewing other calendars but can't select a specific day.

Is is possibile?

Comment: If your question is simply 'is it possible?', then the answer is simply yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the solution [here](http://tokenposts.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/jquery-datepicker-disable-specific.html).

```
var unavailableDates = ["16-7-2013","17-7-2013","18-7-2013"];

function unavailable(date) {
  dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
  if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) < 0) {
    return [true,"","Book Now"];
  } else {
    return [false,"","Booked Out"];
  }
}

$('.datePicker').datepicker({ beforeShowDay: unavailable });
```

this is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vandalo/96LaR/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to know that the click event is bound to the `td` tags inside the picker's DOM. Considering that, you'll probably have to alter the `data-handler` or the `data-event` fields of the cells representing the days, or directly unbind the click event from the table cells. I suggest you take a look into this page of the documentation http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/ where they hold an inline picker like the one you suggest you have. Try executing some jquery scripts until you find the one that fits your needs better.